# How to inject or import libraries in the tapestry core stack to a component?

Tags: requirejs, tapestry

I'm using tapestry 5.4.1. I have a component with a module that requires prototype. I know prototype is available in the core stack. However how do I import this as a dependency.

My module:

```
define(["prototype"], function(container, link) {
  return new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater(container, link, {
      method : 'post', frequency : 5, decay : 1
  });
});
```

I tried adding this to the class but the path cannot be resolved

```
@Import(library = {"prototype.js"})
public class Update {
```

Tried injecting the asset and adding it to the environmental javascriptsupport but it somehow looks for it in the wrong location.

```
@Inject
@Path("classpath:META-INF/assets/tapestry5/prototype.js")
private Asset prototype;
```

and

```
javascriptSupport.importJavaScriptLibrary(prototype);
javascriptSupport.require("update").with(container, getLink());
```

I don't want to hard code the url with the generated hash.

```
/assets/meta/z67bxxxx/tapestry5/scriptaculous_1_9_0/prototype.js
```

Anything I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define correct infrastructure in your AppModule

```
@ApplicationDefaults
public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration) {

    configuration.add(SymbolConstants.JAVASCRIPT_INFRASTRUCTURE_PROVIDER, "prototype");
}
```

You don't have to specify dependency clearly ["prototype"].

Comment: Prototype is already available. Do you think it being under scriptalicious is the problem? The default provider is prototype and I am not changing it to jquery at any point.

Comment: I think you cannot use prototype directly, only tapestry wrappers: (function() {
 define(["t5/core/dom", "t5/core/events", "t5/core/console", 't5/core/ajax'], function(dom, events, console, ajax) { }).call(this);